# Unity Editor upload file to PreSignedURL

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, amazon-s3

** ADDING FIXES
Content Type Removed
Python Changed to presigned url

My goal is to publish my generated WebGL code to my web server for a open source plugin for Unity im working on.  AWSSDK does NOT work in the Editor so I figured I would generated a presigned URL on my web server and pass it to unity like below.

```
# Generate the POST attributes
s3.generate_presigned_url(
'put_object', Params={
    'Bucket': 'webgl-assets',
    'Key': 'media/somethig.unityasset',
    'ACL': 'public-read',
},
ExpiresIn=36000
```

)

## GENERATES

https://webgl-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/media/sonethig.unityasset?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIDJJ2J32&Signature=QLbXw2J12H3HJHh213Dw%3D&x-amz-acl=public-read&Expires=1532583586

Then on my C# side in Unity during Editor mode I try to call the URL like below

```
public void UploadToS3(string filePath, string key)
{
    string URL = "https://webgl-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/media/file.unityweb?key=media%2Ffile.unityweb&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIA&policy=eyJDg6Mjg6MzRaIiwgImNvbmRpdGlvbnMiOiBbeyJidWNrZXQiOiAibXhsdmwtd2ViZ2wtYXNzZXRzIn0sIHsia2V5IjogIm1lZGlhL2ZpifV19&signature=8m4CR8mfzgJX4TeTD";
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Put(URL, System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));
    www.Send();

    while (www.responseCode == 0)
    {
        //do something, or nothing while blocking
    }
    Debug.Log("Send Response: " + www.responseCode + " ");
}
```

The response is a 403 - I tried copying a JS example of doing this and convert it to C#, but my C# is too rusty to get this.  Has anyone tackled a similar problem?

Comment: `"content-type"` should be `"Content-Type"`

Comment: Thanks, Im fixing things as I find them, will update as I work on this.